# Visa requirements for Malaysian citizen - train to Thailand, plane to Malaysia

Tags: visas, trains, passports, thailand, malaysia

I'm Malaysian and travelling to Thailand via train and coming back via airplane.

Please advise on travelling documents needed while entering / exiting Thailand.

Comment: How long are you going to be in Thailand for?

Answer (score 4):

Malaysians can enter Thailand without a visa for up to 30 days.  If you plan to stay longer you need a tourist visa.

The Immigration officials may require proof of departure, for which a copy of your flight booking will suffice and they may require proof of financial support, which for a single person is 10,000 Baht or the equivalent in Ringgit (they maybe OK with a lesser amount in cash if you have a couple of credit cards from major banks).

Answer (score 2):

Malaysian citizens do not need a visa to visit Thailand. See the [embassy guidelines for visa requirements](http://www.thaiembassyuk.org.uk/?q=node/188).

So all you would need is a valid passport.